# MySQL Query condition implies more than stated

Tags: mysql

I want to extract newsletter delivery addresses for a village from 'land' table excluding known residents in 'person' table who have email addresses `email` or who have died (`class`='D'). All addresses are known but not all residents. I have tried:

```
$delQuery=
SELECT streetNum, streetName 
FROM land 
LEFT JOIN person ON land.personID=person.personID 
WHERE (
    email='' 
    OR email IS NULL
) AND class<>'D'.
```

The output excludes all addresses where `class` is null, that is, addresses for unlisted residents. If I make the last condition: AND (class<>'D' OR class IS NULL) the query works OK. The default for `class` is NULL. It seems that class<>'D' implies another condition that class is not null. Why?

Comment: Your question is wishy-washy.  Clarify, Class is in the PERSON table?  Also, what do you WANT.  You are looking for null email and class NOT 'D'.  Since the class is part of the where, that is killing your LEFT JOIN and turning it into an INNER JOIN.  Please clarify.

Comment: Both `class` and `email` are in the person table and I think should be in the WHERE condition.  The query works correctly but only if I have `OR class IS NULL` after 'class<>'D'` (as above). How does 'class<>'D' exclude instances of NULL?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment asking for clarification... The failure is due to your attempt to use a left-join, but then adding the WHERE clause explicitly looking for a value.  By not testing for NULL turns it back to an INNER JOIN.

It is completely legit to put your qualifying conditions directly at the join level to restrict what you do/don't want.  Your original query revised to retain the left-join conditions.  I just changed to use alias "L" and "P" for shorter readability, and it's a great habit to get into so asking for help, nobody needs to guess which columns are associated with which table sources.  Qualify all columns.

```
SELECT 
      L.streetNum, 
      L.streetName 
   FROM 
      land L
         LEFT JOIN person P
            ON L.personID = P.personID 
           AND ( (  P.email IS NULL  OR P.email='' ) 
                AND P.class <> 'D' )
```

So, since the other parts of your criteria were just in the person, I moved those elements to the left-join.  So the way the above SQL is structured, you would get ALL land locations regardless of a person.

If what you want is only for those records that DO HAVE A PERSON associated with the land (require that portion), but also have a valid email (not blank/null) and not deceased, you will need to pull that portion into the where, but you will need to keep it with the where, but lets try to really know what is being asked.  Since I still did not get what you wanted from your query, the query below will get all records that, at a minimum, DO HAVE a person record via (P.PersonID IS NOT NULL).  From that, only include those that HAVE NO EMAIL and have either NULL or not deceased 'D' flag for the class.

```
SELECT 
      L.streetNum, 
      L.streetName 
   FROM 
      land L
         LEFT JOIN person P
            ON L.personID = P.personID 
   WHERE
          P.PersonID IS NOT NULL
      AND ( 
             (  P.email IS NULL  OR P.email='' ) 
            AND P.class IS NOT NULL 
            AND P.class <> 'D' ))
```

Comment: I want to deliver newsletters to all addresses except those that have emails and to deceased people. Alternative 1 selects all addresses regardless.  Alternative 2 omits addresses where the occupant is unknown through `P.PersonID IS NOT NULL`. (Remember, we have all addresses for the village but many of the occupants are unknown.) You are missing the point; my query works but it requires the last condition to be `class<>'D' OR class IS NULL`. My question is: why is `OR class IS NULL` necessary? In other words, why would `class<>'D'` exclude instances of NULL?